# Passing array from activity to fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

while passing an array to fragment that can be show nullpointerexception on putStringArray() method, what i do for that exception

```
Cursor test=db.rawQuery("select * from message",null);
test.moveToFirst();
String[] messages=new String[test.getCount()];
if(test.getCount()>0) 
{
    do 
    {
        if(test.getString(2).equals(mob))
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You\n" + test.getString(1), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        else
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), test.getString(2)+"\n" + test.getString(1), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } while (test.moveToNext());
}
data.putStringArray("messages", messages);
data.putString("number", mob);
```

**ERROR**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{...............................}: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: you did not put anything in your array ,right?

Answer (score 0):

In your activity declare a class scope for your array. Then in your fragment just call

```
((YourActivityClass)getActivity()).<Your array>
```

to access the array directly. No need to pass

Comment: i know that, but the error shows that data.putStringArray("messages", messages); method ???

Comment: Where is the data declared?

Comment: above code is inside in a method and call in oncreate() method in activity

Comment: thanks about your co-operation. Finally I am find a solution about this question

Answer (score 0):

the code start with a method.

```
private Bundle showMessages()
{

    Bundle extra=new Bundle();
    Cursor test=db.rawQuery("select * from message",null);
    test.moveToFirst();
    String[] messages=new String[test.getCount()];

    int i=0;
    if(test.getCount()>0) {
        do {
            if(test.getString(2).equals(mob)) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You\n" + test.getString(1), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                messages[i]="You\n" + test.getString(1);
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), test.getString(2) + "\n" + test.getString(1), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                messages[i]=test.getString(2) + "\n" + test.getString(1);
            }

            i++;
        } while (test.moveToNext());
    }
    //data.putString("message",valu);
    extra.putStringArray("messages", messages);
    extra.putString("number", mob);
    return extra;
}
```

and **invoked** by

```
Bundle bundle=new Bundle(showMessages());
```